# ruby on rails model method loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

The title is probably not the best, but here is my question. I have a rails model with this method

```
def stats(event_id)
  while true do
     sleep 1
     response = HTTParty.get (xxx)
     response
  end
end
```

I continuously stream the response to the client and then I have a client script that calls this method whenever a user click on another event.

in my head, I think there is an issue. whenever the client script calls this method again, a new instance is created (in the controller) which means i'm streaming 2x to the client (the previous one and the new instance).

How can I get this to work? I need this instance to exist once for each user so no duplicate data is streamed and previous instances for the user should stop whenever a new request is made.

I don't mind moving this to the controller if it helps. Also, you access the streaming page only if you are logged in.

Thanks.

Comment: This smells so bad I don't now where to start. Don't solve this problem with MVC Rails, and certainly not with a loop in a model. Let the client fetch the data with JS (if possible), or google for websockets.

Comment: lol. exactly...i thought so. I have a js script that polls for new data...was just thinking if I can have the server do that and stream to the client

Comment: `sleep` in a web app is a cardinal sin. That aside, you should look into websockets or long polling; let the loop live on the client.

Comment: OK thanks. I have that. I guess my intuition on not doing this on the server was right.

Comment: i ran into some polling issues. i posted a question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046787/abort-ajax-request-and-restart-request-with-new-parameter